# Error installing etetoolkit. When installing using anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, etetoolkit

I followed the [directions](http://etetoolkit.org/download/) to install etetoolkit for mac.

```
# Install Minconda  (you can ignore this step if you already have Anaconda/Miniconda)
curl -L 'http://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-MacOSX-x86_64.sh' -o Miniconda3-latest-MacOSX-x86_64.sh
bash Miniconda3-latest-MacOSX-x86_64.sh -b -p ~/anaconda_ete/
export PATH=~/anaconda_ete/bin:$PATH;

# Install ETE and external tools 
conda install -c etetoolkit ete3 ete_toolchain

# Check installation
ete3 build check
```

I get an error when I run `conda install -c etetoolkit ete3 ete_toolchain`

Error:

> UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be
>   incompatible with the existing python installation in your
>   environment:
>
> - ete3 -> python[version='>=2.7,<2.8.0a0,>=3.5,<3.6.0a0,>=3.6,<3.7.0a0']
> - ete_toolchain -> python[version='>=2.7,<2.8.0a0,>=3.5,<3.6.0a0,>=3.6,<3.7.0a0'

Answer (score 0):

1. I ran the [package installer][2] for anaconda 3.7.  (I don't think I actually had to do this.)
2. From terminal run: `conda install python=2.7`
3. Then `conda install -c etetoolkit ete3 ete_toolchain`

Then I verified this worked by running `ete3 build check`.  In the results `clustalo: MISSING` displayed, but that's a new problem to solve.

**UPDATE**

The final problem was solved by running `conda install -c etetoolkit ete3_external_apps`

*There is a type-o in the instructions given by ete3.  Use this instead.*